# Strength of wall regarding a system of hanging mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statics

[image]

When we assume that mass m is directly at the center of L, and $\alpha$ is the angle between the rope and the horizontal, I am able to show that for equilibrium, $$\sin{\alpha}=\frac{m}{2M}$$
There is also a resultant reaction force from the roller due to the resultant of left side tension and weight of M (which are equal in case of equilibrium). However, let's say that there is a constraint as to how much of a load the wall anchor can hold. Assuming M is still kept the same, how do I proceed to calculate $m_{max}$ and $\alpha$ in that case?

Comment: What's the "wall anchor"? The right side structure?

Comment: Yes, there is a roller to the left and a wall to the right.

Comment: OK, so the structure to the right is the wall. Then how is the rope attached to the wall?

Comment: Well I assume its just mounted to the wall. The wall would provide a certain reaction force to the pull of the right side tension. As to the constraint I mentioned, would perhaps be the maximum reaction force the wall can provide (hence the load)

Comment: When you say "let's say that there is a constraint as to how much of a load the wall anchor can hold", you need to say what you mean by "hold". Do you mean the maximum force before the said "anchor" pulls out of the wall"?  If that's the case, it may depend as much on the type of anchor being used as the strength of the wall itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completely sure what you mean with the maximum load that the wall anchor can hold. But one way or the other that is either the tension force $T$ in the rope, or $T\cos\alpha$ or $T\sin\alpha$.

You equate this load to the maximum tension force. The unknown are $m$ and $\alpha$. Together with the equation for equilibrium that you already showed in the question, you end up with two equations with two unknown.

Comment: I think the first sentence of your answer says it all.Calculating the components of the reaction at the wall is simple. As I pointed out in my comments, what it means with respect to the "maximum load the wall anchor can hold" depends on both the anchor and the strength of the wall.

Comment: Exactly. That was why I was confused in the first place. I will assume by maximum load the question means maximum tension T in the rope. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Anon if you have got the answer then please click on the tick on the left of the answer